# AWS Amplify AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

To connect my existing DynamoDB table as a data source in my amplify graphQL schema how to do that?

i am trying below schema in aws amplify app sync

type Todo @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) @dataSource(name: "TodoTable") {
id: ID!
name: String!
description: String
}

and i run a cmd in amplify api gql-compile, it's return the

Schema validation failed.
There can be only one type named "Query".
Unknown directive "@dataSource".